# How can I smoothen out these edges?

Tags: edges, smooth

How can I smoothen out these pointed edges? I've tried beveling them, subsurface modifiers and subdivide + shade smooth but they didnt help too much.[image: the jagged edges are mostly on the main fuselage of the plane model.]

Comment: hello, could you please share the object (at least the cylinder)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: An Edit Mode screenshot of the part giving you trouble could help us see if the topology is causing it, but generally sharing the .blend file with us (as moonboots asked above) is what's needed to get a good answer.

Comment: You'd generally be using subdivision to smooth out the silhouette.  That doesn't work here for a few reasons: 1) the mesh is triangulated 2) the mesh has disconnected vertices 3) the mesh has edges that join more than 2 faces 4) the mesh has custom normals built around all of those weird things.  First thing to do is to fix the mesh; here, merge by distance won't help, because it will create additional non-manifold verts.

Answer (score 0):

The topology is causing you trouble:

[image]

The structure you're trying to round out via subdivision is made of trigons, which don't respond well to subdivision.  Retopologizing to all-quads would probably help.

There's other issues with the mesh you uploaded, like a lot of doubling, which may make more sense to recreate it from scratch.